# The default constructor in an child of std::runtime_error

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, default-constructor

I have two exception classes that inherit from std::runtime_error. The first one, `AError`, works just fine.

```
class AError : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    const char* what() const noexcept
    {
        return "Error of type A!";
    }
};
```

The second one, `BError`, does not compile because `std::runtime_error` does not have a default constructor.

```
class BError : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    const int num_;

    BError(int n) : num_(n) {}; // ERROR: no default constructor for runtime_error

    const char* what() const noexcept
    {
        return "Error of type B!";
    }
};
```

It seems to me that `AError` should not compile because the default constructor of `AError` should call the default constructor of `std::runtime_error` in the default constructor `AError`. What is happening in the default constructor of `AError` that allows that example to compile?

Comment: You haven't posted any code that constructs an object of type `AError`.  Please post code that can be used to test your concerns.

Comment: I have made a terrible mistake. This post should be closed.

Comment: @mana Then, simply delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to me that AError should not compile because the default constructor of AError should call the default constructor of std::runtime_error in the default constructor AError.

The default ctor of `AError` is deleted because it inherits from a class that has no default ctor. try the following and the code won't compile

```
AError er;
```

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `AError` compiles because it doesn't have a default constructor (one that accepts no arguments).  Implicit generation of the default constructor is suppressed because `std::runtime_error` doesn't have one.   The class definition, in itself, has no diagnosable errors, since it doesn't create any instances of the class.

There is a diagnosable error on any attempt to create an instance of `AError` using a default constructor

```
AError an_error;    // error since AError cannot be default constructed
```

In `BError`, the definition of the constructor (within class `BError`)

> ```
> BError(int n) : num_(n) {}; // ERROR: no default constructor for runtime_error
> ```

attempts to implicitly construct the base `std::runtime_error`, even though it is not listed in the initialiser list.   So this definition is functionally equivalent to

```
BError(int n) : std::runtime_error(), num_(n) {};
```

and is a diagnosable error, due to the attempt - clearly visible to the compiler - to use the (non-existent) default constructor of `std::runtime_error`.

You can make this compile by simply using an appropriate constructor from `std::runtime_error`, such as

```
BError(int n) : std::runtime_error(""), num_(n) {};
```

which will call the constructor of `std::runtime_error` that accepts a `const char *`.